# What is wrong here with OneHotEncoding()?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

[Please Open the Image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h953.png)

All the problem is with Embarked Attribute. Whenever in onehotencoding() I remove column no 11, the fit_transform() works fine. But when I add the 11th column again, i get the Value error saying input contains NaN.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnTransformer` does not apply its transformers sequentially, it does so in parallel.  So the 11th column going into the Encoder doesn't do so *after* having been imputed, and `OneHotEncoder` fails on data with missing values.

You could use a `Pipeline` with steps Impute and Encode, and use that only for column 11 in the `ColumnTransformer`.